# How to get only updated data form Mysql database and store into sqlite database in android?

Tags: android, web-services, mysqli, synchronization, android-sqlite

Please could anyone let me know how can I get only updated data from Mysql database if internet is available? Actually I am making web request to server to fetch data and store it into sqlite local database but it get all the data from server every time and store into sqlite database actually its waisting of time if i have 10000 records it will take long to download it every time another way I want to check first if there is any updated data fetch only those rows of data and store into local sqlite database. I have searched a lot but did not get any specific response. Please could anyone tell me how can I do this?
Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

Send last downloaded record ID to server and ask for records having ID > last downloaded ID

Comment: You can get last downloaded ID from local sqlite database

Comment: No what if he changes some previous data  row like Address or phone number then?

Comment: In such a case, add some extra column as FLAG indicating 'true' for data has changed.
Update the column value for specific record to 'true' when data is updated